# Inequation of limit of an integral

Tags: integration, limits

Consider the functions $f_n: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$,$$ \: f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x(x^n + 1)}, \:\:n \in \mathbb N^*$$

and $F_n:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ the primitive of $f_n$ that goes through the point $A(1, 0).$

**Solve the inequation:**

$$|\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x)| \le 1$$

I tried the substitution $\ln x = u$ with no results, also rewrote $1 = \int_{0}^1dx$ but it didn't help.

Comment: What is $A(1,0)$ and $G_{F_n}$?

Comment: @mickep edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\frac{1}{x(1+x^n)}=\frac{1+x^n-x^n}{x(1+x^n)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n}.
$$
Do you see what a primitive function is now?

Comment: Ok, so the primitive is $\ln x - \frac{1}{n} \ln(x^n + 1)$, because I have found the constant from the integration is 0. What can I do now ? Do I have to separate this for $x > 1$ and $x \le 1$ ?

Comment: Inserting $x=1$ in $\ln x-(1/n)\ln(1+x^n) gives you $-(1/n)\ln 2$, so I think you have the wrong constant.

Comment: But for n going to infinity, doesn't that go to $0$ ? Could you help me with a hint to continue solving this ?